# Change the look of Swing

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way to change the standard look of Swing components? Those default, look just pathetic and hopelesly unattractive.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For information, the default is the "Metal" look and feel, which was created by Sun as an alternative to the Windows 95/98 appearance, which explains the "unattractive", as of today's standards.

You can use the "system" look and feel, which will be a copy of what your system has (more or less):

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

There are other LaF available, like described in the other answers. The "Nimbus" is the new "Metal", developed by Sun as an alternative of today's standards. It is still young, though, and there are still things to fix and adjust.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can manually set a different look and feel.

Have a look at the following links

- [Lesson: Modifying the Look and Feel](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html)
- [20+ Free Look and Feel Libraries for Java Swings](http://javabyexample.wisdomplug.com/privacy-policy/37-core-java/65-20-free-look-and-feel-libraries-for-java-swings.html)

You can even write your own custom look and feel if you like.

- [How to Write a Custom Look and Feel](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/09/12/how-to-write-custom-look-and-feel.html)

Comment: Could you please point me in the right direction on how to do it?

Comment: Is it possible to make them look like native Windows?

Comment: only if you're on a windows platform (licensing restrictions): http://www.iam.ubc.ca/guides/javatut99/uiswing/misc/plaf.html  ("Currently, you can use this look and feel only on Win32 systems.")

Comment: As someone else pointed out, just use:
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
If you are on a Windows platform, it will get a Windows "native like" LaF.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [JGoodies](http://www.jgoodies.com/) - specifically their Looks libraries.  It has tutorials and such about how to set its different look and feels

Answer (score 1):

There's [Nimbus](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/otherFeatures/nimbus_laf.html) for a more attractive default from Sun, provided in 1.6.10+.  You can also find many different look and feels through [Substance](https://substance.dev.java.net/).